# Why in html a variable is automatically rounding up but not in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

See this below demo code-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
var d="[86.69043189999999";
    var c = d.match(/-?\d*\.{0,1}\d+/);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = c;
document.write("<td><button id='button' type='button' onclick='alert("+c+")'>click</button></td>")
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Here output for innerHtml is  `86.69043189999999`

But for the alert box the output is  `86.6904319`

Any idea why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alert always returns a string, and the way it converts a number to a  string is with the [toString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toString) method:

```js
var num = 86.69043189999999.toString();
console.log(num);
document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = num
```

```html
<div id='test'></div>
```

[for more info check the specs of conversion.](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.8.1)

Answer (score 0):

In the alert, the type is Number. Numbers in Javascript are floating points and they are have limited precision. Hence you see the limited precision value `86.6904319`

In the innerHTML case you are setting the innerHTML to the string representation of the array of matches i.e. ['86.69043189999999']. Here the string result (a sequence of characters) is output as is.

This will clear if you do something like

```
var d="[86.69043189999999";
var c = d.match(/-?\d*\.{0,1}\d+/);
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = typeof(c);
document.write("<td><button id='button' type='button' onclick='alert(typeof("+c+"))'>click</button></td>")
```

The document will have `object` and the alert will show `number`

Answer (score 0):

Your number starts out as a string. When setting `innerHTML`, you're still setting a string value, no interpretation of the value is done as a number.

However, here: `"alert("+c+")"`, you're producing this new snippet of Javascript code:

```
alert(86.69043189999999)
```

The number is being evaluated as a float literal for the first time, not as a string. And since floats have limited precision, you cannot expect the value to stay exactly as it is. If you want to continue to treat it as a string, you need to quote it using `alert('" + c + "')"`, producing:

```
alert('86.69043189999999')
```

HTML doesn't "round" anything; through missing quotation you're merely causing your value to be type cast into a float, in the process of which you're losing precision.